# HTML/Javascript Ascending Number

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to make a simple javascript game. Basically, you get pancakes at a certain amount per second. In the code, I call this value (**the rate at which you get pancakes**) pps. I want to make it so that as the HTML span tag that shows the total amount of pancakes gets more pancakes, (**at the rate of pps**), it ascends so it looks nicer.

For example, if I get pancakes at `5` pps, right now it just goes `0, 5, 10,` etc... every second. I want it to go `0,1,2,3,4,5(1 second)`, next second `6,7,8,9,10,` etc...

Here is the code that I have so far, for the pancake counter:

```
pps = 100;
tp = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  tp += parseInt(pps);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = tp;
}, 1000);
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please show the relevant code. But if I was forced to guess, I'd say you are doing something like `setTimeout(function() { pancakes += pps; }, 1000)`? Do `setTimeout(function() { pancakes++; }, 1000 / pps)`.

Comment: Yes, by writing some code… ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem common to all games, and one that you need to solve correctly for your game to work outside of your own computer.

The correct solution is that you need to measure the elasped time between each iteration of your game loop, or between each frame render. This is, in practice, going to be a very small number; you can think of this number as a "scaling factor".

If your game was about moving a space ship, and you wanted it to move 5 screen units per second, your game loop would:

- Find the time elapsed since the last interval, in seconds. In a game rate-limited to 60 frames-per-second, this would be around 1/60th of a second
- Multiply the ship's speed (5 units per second) by 1/60; the ship would move 0.8333... units this tick
- move the ship by that amount.

By the time 1 full second has passed, the ship will have moved 5 units. 
The exact same principal applies to your PPS.

The important part is that, in the real world, it will **not** be exactly 1/60th of a second between frames. If you're not computing the "scaling factor" each iteration of your loop, your game will slowly accrue error. **`setInterval` is particularly bad for this**, and not at all suitable as a source for time in a game.

The implementation in JavaScript is simple: Each game loop, record the current time from whatever source of time is available to you; in your case, you can use `get Date().getTime()`, which returns the time since the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. Record this value.

In the subsequent redraw, you will again call `get Date().getTime()`, and then subtract the previous value to the the elapsed time. That is your scaling factor, in milliseconds. You can multiply `pps` by that value to determine how many pancakes to add.

It's important that you still follow this approach, even if you're using `setInterval`. You might think you can simply `setInterval(..., 1000 / 60)` to invoke your callback 60 times per second, but `setInterval` (and `setTimeout`) are not accurate - they invoke your callback **at least** that far in the future, but potentially much further. You still need to scale `pps` by the elapsed times since the last redraw.

Here's a simple implementation:

```js
var PPS = 5;
var lastTime = new Date().getTime();
var cakes = 0;

setInterval(function () {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime()
  var elapsedTime = currentTime - lastTime;

  lastTime = currentTime;
  
  cakes += (PPS * (elapsedTime / 1000)) // elapsedTime is in milliseconds, divide by 1000 to get fractional seconds
  
  document.getElementById('pps').innerText = cakes;
  
  
}, 10);
```

```html
<div id="pps"></div>
```

---

As an aside, the *incorrect* solution is one you find in a lot of old games: Increment things as fast as you can. On old computers this was a viable solution; the game redrew slowly enough that the game would advance smoothly. As computers got faster, the game would *run* faster, until it became unplayable.

Comment: Unless fractional values are acceptable in the display, the innerText should be set to `Math.floor(cakes)`.

Answer (score -1):

A simple interval timer would do the trick. Something like this:

```
function incrementToNumber(tag, currentNumber, targetNumber) {
    var numTicks = targetNumber - currentNumber;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        currentNumber++;
        tag.innerText = currentNumber;
        if(currentNumber == targetNumber) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000 / numTicks);
}
```

That particular function increments over the course of one second. To change the time it takes to increment, swap out the `1000` with whatever milliseconds you want it to take.

For a version that increases forever:

```
function inrementForever(tag, currentPancakes, pancakesPerSecond) {
    setInterval(function() {
        currentPancakes++;
        tag.innerText = currentPancakes;
    }, 1000 / pancakesPerSecond);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure I completely understand this, I'm sorry, I'm relatively new to this. So if I have something like this:
`pps = 100;
tp = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  tp += parseInt(pps);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = tp;
}, 1000);`
Where tp is total pancakes and pps is pancakes per second, how can I alter this code to make it like the one that you just posted?

Comment: OK, one thing to note about my version is that it stops incrementing once it reaches the top. I'll edit the answer with a version that increments forever.

Comment: You definitely don't want to call `document.getElementById` inside your loop/timer. Call it once, store the element somewhere, and just reference it later.

Comment: @user3385777 Please don't use this method, you cannot rely on `setInterval` to regularly invoke it's callback. If your browser stalls for any reason, the calculation will be thrown off and will not recover. This is a *huge* problem, many things cause `setInterval` to invoke its callback at a much slower rate than you actually request. My method is immune to this problem, and is the industry-accept solution to this problem.

Comment: @meagar is correct about the unreliability of the `setInterval` call timing. It doesn't fire immediately at the specified time. It instead queues up an event that may not fire for a long time if you have any long-running functions.  I still suggest pre-loading the span element instead of grabbing it each time in the loop, but overall his solution is safer.

Comment: @meagar Ok thanks so much. Just one thing I noticed, for meagar's method, there is very long decimal places. Do you know of a way for me to remove those decimals? Thanks to both of you for your help, it means alot.

Comment: for @meagar's method, `cake += parseInt(PPS * (elapsedTime / 1000))` to deal with rounding errors. It's hacky (it convers to string, then turns back to int), but it works.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Don't use `parseInt(...)`. Use `Math.floor(...)` and only use it for setting the text, not the actual cakes value. Cakes needs to retain it's floating-point values.

Comment: Be sure to mark @meagar's answer as the correct one for future visitors.